# NASM | Segmentation fault

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Есть код `test.asm` для теста:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, [0xfbef8000]
    int 0x80
```

Далее получаю исполняемый файл ELF для i386:

```
nasm -f elf test.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o test test.o
```

При запуске получаю ошибку `Segmentation fault`.

Мне необходимо считать 4 байта, расположенные по конкретному адресу. Почему возникает ошибка?

Comment: Кажеться надо сохранить и восстановить регистры, до и после вызова соответственно. Верните еах в исходное положение :) и вы не считывание адрес, вы присваиваете еах конкретное значение.

Comment: вы загружаете в eax значение по жестко указанному адресу, относительно своего сегмента данных, почему вы уверены, что этот адрес допустим и доступен для вашего приложения ? Далее вы вызываете int 80, который будет выполнять системный вызов ядра ОС, причем в eax он получает номер функции, которую надо выполнить. Вы уверены, что хотите выполнить некую функцию ядра, зависящую от содержимого некой ячейки памяти, при том, что значения других регистров, которые то же обычно нужны вы не оговариваете. Вы же понимаете, что этой функцией может оказаться, например, "стереть все с диска"

Comment: @Mike да, я понимаю, но делаю это чисто в целях обучения. Мне хотелось бы понять механизм (последовательность) выполнения подобного кода процессором. То есть, что именно и почему вызывает подобное исключение.

Comment: Подобные вещи вообще надо в отладчике смотреть. Но думаю что первая же инструкция, скорее всего в адресном пространстве вашего процесса нет адреса 0xfbef8000. Если же он все таки есть, то ошибку может вызвать и int 80, если он например ожидает получить для той операции, которая у вас вышла, какой нибудь указатель в каком нибудь из регистров и пытается по нему обратится

Comment: Лучше начать примерно [вот от сюда](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions)

Comment: А еще у вас нет завершения программы, так что segfauilt может быть и после int 80